Rails - How to Create Association to 2 Sub-classes Part of SIngle Table Inheritance
So I have set up Single Table Inheritance so I can create two sub-classes for the User table. In my current implementation, both subclasses will have the exact same fields so STI makes sense here I think.
    class User < ApplicationRecord
    end

    class Student < User
    end

    class Teacher < User
    end

    class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
    end

I want to create an Appointment model that has a many-to-one association with Students and also many-to-one association with Teachers. But since Students and Teachers belong to the same Users table, how would I create the db migration to make the association to those models?
    class CreateAppointments < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
      def change
        create_table :appointments do |t|
          t.datetime :start_datetime
          t.references :users, null: false, foreign_key: true
#         t.references :users, null: false, foreign_key: true  --> this one should be for students
          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end

Does it make sense for me to keep on using STI or should I create separate tables at this point for students and teachers? It just doesn't make much sense to me at the moment because they have the exact same fields. But then it would become much easier to make the Appointment associations.

@dbugger No unfortunately it doesn't because in that case, the answer did not even discuss an STI solution, and furthermore those models seem to be a bit different whereas my subclasses would be nearly identical.

@dbugger actually after a second look, despite the answer stating it's not STI, it does still look like STI is being used there. I think that may potentially work for me. I will give it a try and report back. Thanks.

However, I am still wondering if it would be possible to declare two foreign keys to the same table that uses STI within the migration file, like I'm trying to do in the code sample.

Ok, so I'm now surprised to see that the answer went over my head this whole time. The migration I needed to do:
 class CreateAppointments < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :appointments do |t|
      t.datetime :start_datetime
      t.references :teacher, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :student, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :teacher, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :student, class_name: "User"
end


class Student < User
    has_many :appointments, foreign_key: :student_id
end

class Teacher < User
    has_many :appointments, foreign_key: :teacher_id
end

I thought you could only reference models with tables via t.references, but it appears by using the sub-classes teacher and student, Rails knows to look in the users table for those associations.

Upon further testing, I am getting the following error when attempting to save an Appointment object: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.students (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid). Any suggestions on possible fixes? I may just have to avoid STI.

I would advice you avoid STI altogether, thing can easily get messy when using STI.  For the sql error, your migration file looks wrong, it should look like
t.references :teacher, null: false, foreign_key: { to_table: :table_name }

@chrisgeeq I tried your suggestion and I still get the error SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.teachers (SQLite3::SQLException). I tried spring stop and resetting the DB per a different thread, but I'm getting the same SQLite error when running rake db:schema:load.

@chrisgeeq I reset my db, updated my migration to set that value for foreign_key, and this time it worked. Thanks!
